# Error View in Map v2 Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, android-maps-v2

I use actionbar tabs and `ViewPager` for create tabs and swiping between tabs. I use `SherlockFragmentActivity` for tabs page adapter.and for each item extends fragment. This project is ok for all pages just in the locationmap page(fragment) for first time it's works but when i change tabs and then return for second time the locationmap page crashes.
line of Error: view

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_location_map, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

tabAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new ViewSiteFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ViewSiteInfoFragment();
        case 2:
            return new LocationMapFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a logcat of the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: 11-26 12:11:02.328: E/AndroidRuntime(20769): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f050039, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: anybody can't help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to the fact that you are trying to inflate a fragment inside a fragment.  You should be extending `SupportMapFragment` instead of wrapping it another fragment.  Delete your layout file and remove your `onCreateView()` method.  Then make `LocationMapFragment` extend `SupportMapFragment`

```
public class LocationMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    // code here without onCreateView
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,but it's  error for me..can you put complete code for us?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you iagreen .I could resolve My problem.

complete code:

```
public class LocationMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment  {

    private LatLng mPosition;


    public LocationMapFragment() {
        super();

    }

    public static LocationMapFragment newInstance(LatLng posicion){
        LatLng l=new LatLng(35.722838,51.371342);
        LocationMapFragment frag = new LocationMapFragment();
        frag.mPosition; = l;
        return frag;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
          View v = super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
          initMap();
           return v;
    }

    private void initMap(){
        UiSettings settings = getMap().getUiSettings();
        settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        settings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
       LatLng mPath=new LatLng(35.722838,51.371342);
        getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mPath,16));
        getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mPath).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

        getJson();

    }
}
```